# Pandas not throwing exception when using setitem

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Here's a minimal, complete and verifiable example of a piece of code that surprises (and bothers) me:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], columns = ['a','b'])
>>> df['a'].iloc[0,0] = 10 # df has not changed, and no exception is thrown
>>> df 
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4
>>> df['a'].iloc[0,0] # this throws an exception
IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
```

So when I call setitem with `iloc[0,0]` no exception is raised, but nothing is set.
When I call `getitem` with `iloc[0,0]` an exception is raised. This seems fairly inconsistent to me. I would have expected either both `getitem` and `setitem` to raise an exception, or both to return me a scalar within the dataframe.

Comment: even with `x = df['a'].iloc ; x[0,0] = 10 ; print(x[0,0])` gives same error!

Comment: This might need someone who knows how to look at assembly.

Answer (score 1):

As you might know, `df['a']` is a series because,

> the primary function of indexing with [] (a.k.a. **getitem** for those
>   familiar with implementing class behavior in Python) is selecting out
>   lower-dimensional slices.
>
> [**Basics**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#basics)

So there is no column. You cannot use `.iloc[0, Fail!]` hence `df['a'].iloc[0, 0]` exception is normal.

Regarding no exception of `df['a'].iloc[0, 0] = 10`, it's intended.

> it's very hard to predict whether it will return a view or a copy (it
>   depends on the memory layout of the array, about which pandas makes no
>   guarantees)
>
> **[Returning a view versus a copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)**
>
> **[Why does assignment fail when using chained indexing?](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing)**

FYI, if you want to change the value of df (0, 0), you should try this way.

```
df.iloc[0, 0] = 10 
df.ix[0, 'a'] = 10 
df.loc[0, 'a'] = 10
```